# ionic framework on transition of page or navigation displaying black screen

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have been stuck on problem related to the ionic framework in which , whenever I click on slide menu then befor page slide, dark black color occurring like black box in iPhone and iPad, and same it is happing each and every click of slide or transition or navigation.

So any body has solution regarding that please let me know.

Thanks
Shivam

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: Well I found solution in form Thanks

Comment: Found a solution and didn't post it? Not cool dude...

Comment: Sorry my friend , actually no one ask except me,
just follow path lib/ionic/ionic.css and put this code at bottom
[nav-view-transition="ios"][nav-view-direction="forward"], [nav-view-transition="ios"][nav-view-direction="back"] {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add transparency to background between view transition:

`[nav-view-transition][nav-view-direction] {
   background-color: transparent;
 }`

I added the above css to my custom styles.css.

Also, remove any [abstract states](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#abstract-states) and this should fix your black screen issue between navigation(s).